# Optimal way to display long radio buttons on mobile

Tags: forms, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-web, radio-buttons

I'm working on designing a responsive form, and I'm wondering if anyone has ideas for dealing with "long" radio button options on mobile. For example, take the following image:

[image]

I've browsed around the web for ideas a bit, and I've seen suggestions like "use segmented controls" or "use dropdowns"--but that doesn't work when there is a lot of text per radio option.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there a problem with wrapping text to next line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line wrapping and correct indent / whitespacing

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbgFZ1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Spacing between options in above example should be a tad tighter, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question.

**Dropdowns: Nope**

I would hazard against using a dropdown. In general, they're frowned upon for mobile UX because they require a "tap" to view the options, and *another* to select one.

**Segmented Controls: Maybe**

Normally, this is where  I would point you. It might still be an option, depending on your data. Instead of going the traditional route of ["Button Groups"](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups**), it may be worth creating a new component that fits your data better.

**New Componenet: Yes**

This likely has a name, but why not something like this?:

[image]

(I did this in paint. Open to suggestions for a better program).

Where you use some kind of list component where the entire area is tappable/clickable. Just make sure the element has a "selected" state. It's definitely more work, but I think it's a huge improvement for UX.

- More aesthetically pleasing.
- Larger hit area.
- Accommodates longer strings.